# Noise cancellation with fft failing - unable to assign elements

Tags: matlab, indexing, fft

I have the following code for noise cancellation:

```
[z,fs] = audioread('noisy_voices.wav'); % Use >>soundsc(z, fs) to hear the unprocessed signal
zproc_vec=zeros(1,length(z));
tail = zeros(1,256);
for k = 0:128:length(z)-256
Z = fft(z(k +1:k + 256).* hann(256));
[zmax, zl] = max(abs(Z(1:128)));
Z(zl-3: zl +3)=0;
Z(256-(zl-3:zl +3)+2)=0;
zproc = ifft(Z);
zproc = zproc+tail;
tail(1:128) = zproc(129:256);
zproc_vec(k+1:k+256)=zproc;
end
soundsc(zproc_vec , fs)
```

Could anyone tell me why I get this error?

> Unable to perform assignments because the left and right sides have a different number of elements
>
> Error in task_one (line 12)
> zproc_vec(k+1:k+256)=zproc;

Comment: This is basic debugging, which is your job. Check the size of the right hand side of the assignment expression and see if you can find the discrepancy.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [how to debug small programms](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the output of your `Z = fft( ___ )` line will be a column vector, but you initialise `tail` to be a row vector with `tail = zeros(1,256);`

So on this line:

```
zproc = zproc+tail;
```

[Implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) would make `zproc` a square 256*256 matrix.

Then your indexing fails, as specified by the error message, because you're trying to assign this square matrix to the 256 elements you're indexing with `zproc_vec(k+1:k+256)`.

**Initialising `tail` to a column vector should solve the issue.**

Alternatively you could take the "lazy" way out and make sure you're only operating on column vectors to create `zproc`

```
zproc = zproc(:)+tail(:); % Make both terms column vectors for addition
```

Comment: No problem, but no I can't really go through commenting on your code, it's your code not mine! You should [debug](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) your code, step through it line by line, look up functions you don't recognise in the documentation, and write comments which make sense to you

Answer (score -2):

> ''Unable to perform assignments because the left and right sides have a different number of elements''

What part of the error message do you not understand? It means that the variables on the left and the right side of the equal sign have different sizes so you can't assign the right thingy to the left thingy.

Check the sizes and make sure they are the same.

Comment: This is at best a pointer as to where the OP can find an answer or start to debug, rather than the actual answer. I'd reserve this for a comment instead.